# Finding the altitude of an isosceles triangle with base length and angle

Tags: triangles

So I have triangle ABC where:

1. $AC = BC$;
2. $AB$ is known
3. $\hat C$ (the angle $A\hat CB$) is known

I'm trying to find the altitude of said triangle.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{AB}{2\tan\frac{\angle C}{2}}$. Hint: the altitude from $C$ to $AB$ is also the angle bisector of $\angle C$ and the midpoint of $AB$.

Answer (score 0):

AB/2tan(∠C/2) should be the answer! The altitude is the angle bisector